# AJAX form reloading page when calling preventDefault()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mongodb

I have a Node/Express/Mongo app and I am trying to make an AJAX call, the data is now saving fine but the page is reloading even when I user `preventDefault()` in the AJAX call. Why is this happening?

```
var categoryButton = function(){
event.preventDefault();
$("#add_category_form").submit(function (event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({                     //this gets the ID, you have to add a data-id="user._id" to the input you want to send the request from.
        url: $("add_category_form").attr("action"),
        type: "POST",
        dataType: json,
        done: function (result) {
            alert("successful");
            //console.log(result.categories);
        },
        fail: function (fail){
            console.log(fail);
        }
    });
});
};
```

Here is the HTML

```
<section id="event_categories_section"   style="display:none;" class="col-md-6">
                    <form  id="add_category_form" onsubmit="categoryButton" method="POST" action="/user/categories/<%=user._id%>">
                        <label for="input_category_name">Add a category for your Events</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <input  type="submit" id="add_category_button" value="Add Category!" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"></input>
                            </div>
                            <input class="form-control" id="input_category_name" name="user[category]" placeholder="Category Name" required type="text" minlength="2" data-id="<%= user._id %>">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h3>List of Categories</h3>
                        <section class="well" id="list_category_section">
                            <% user.categories.forEach(function(category){ %>
                            <p><%= category %></p>
                            <% }); %>
                        </section>

                    </div>
                </section>
```

Comment: Wrap the ajax calling part with try~catch statement and check has an error.

Answer (score 1):

**Update your code and check**

```
 <section id="event_categories_section"   style="display:none;" class="col-md-6">
                    <form  id="add_category_form"  method="POST" action="/user/categories/<%=user._id%>">
                        <label for="input_category_name">Add a category for your Events</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <input  type="submit" id="add_category_button" value="Add Category!" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle"></input>
                            </div>
                            <input class="form-control" id="input_category_name" name="user[category]" placeholder="Category Name" required type="text" minlength="2" data-id="<%= user._id %>">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h3>List of Categories</h3>
                        <section class="well" id="list_category_section">
                            <% user.categories.forEach(function(category){ %>
                            <p><%= category %></p>
                            <% }); %>
                        </section>

                    </div>
                </section>
```

> Ajax section :-

```
$(function() {
$("#add_category_form").submit(function (event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({                     //this gets the ID, you have to add a data-id="user._id" to the input you want to send the request from.
        url: $("add_category_form").attr("action"),
        type: "POST",
        dataType: json,
        done: function (result) {
            alert("successful");
            //console.log(result.categories);
        },
        fail: function (fail){
            console.log(fail);
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: I dont understand why you removed all of the EJS tags?

Comment: Sorry ... but remove only  ' onsubmit="categoryButton" ' from form and pest my jquery and check

Answer (score 0):

Use `return false` at the end of your `.submit()` function

return false from within a jQuery event handler is effectively the same as calling both event.preventDefault and event.stopPropagation on the passed jQuery.Event object.

`event.preventDefault()` will prevent the default event from occurring.

`event.stopPropagation()` will prevent the event from bubbling up.

Comment: That did not work. My page goes blank and it just has the URL of the post request in the address bar after submitting.

Answer (score 0):

remove the **onsubmit** attribute from the **form** and call the **categoryButton()** function when document is ready, then your submit event will bind with your **form** and everything will work properly.
I just modified little bit your code please try it and share your feedback.

```
   $(function() {
    categoryButton();
    })
var categoryButton = function(){
$("#add_category_form").submit(function (event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({                     //this gets the ID, you have to add a data-id="user._id" to the input you want to send the request from.
        url: $("add_category_form").attr("action"),
        type: "POST",
        dataType: json,
        done: function (result) {
            alert("successful");
            //console.log(result.categories);
        },
        fail: function (fail){
            console.log(fail);
        }
    });
});
};
```

Comment: Ok, this broke everything. The page doesnt reload and the submit button just sits there pressed...... Is this progress?

Comment: just forget my above code and change onsubmit="return false;categoryButton(event);" in html